# Multiple nested observable with SwitchMap

Tags: rxjs, switchmap

In my scenario, I have an higher order observable which when emits we needs to fetch two different pieces of data as inner observables.

something like

```
    $someDetails.pipe(
switchMap(sd => {
this.name = sd.name;
let innerObservableOne = getObservableOne(this.name);
let innerObservableTwo = getObservableTwo(this.name);
return {one: innerObservableOne, two: innerObservableTwo}
}).subscribe(r => ?????)
```

Can I get some lead on this?

Do I need to do something like this

https://medium.com/@snorredanielsen/rxjs-accessing-a-previous-value-further-down-the-pipe-chain-b881026701c1

The other option I have is to use two switchmaps one for each inner observable but that means two subscriptions which seems unnecessary.

```
$someDetails.pipe(
    switchMap(sd => {
    return getObservableOne(sd.name);
}).subscribe(.....);


$someDetails.pipe(
    switchMap(sd => {
    return getObservableTwo(sd.name);
}).subscribe(.....);
```

Edit1:

Any issues with following code:-

What about the following code.

```
details$ = $someDetails.pipe(share());

details$.pipe(switchMap(sd => getObservableOne(sd.name)).subscribe(...);
details$.pipe(switchMap(sd => getObservableTwo(sd.name)).subscribe(...);
```

Any thoughts or issues you see with this solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You want [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin):

```js
import { forkJoin, interval, map, switchMap, timer } from 'rxjs'

interval(1000).pipe(
  switchMap(x => forkJoin([
    timer(100).pipe(map(() => `apple #${x}`)),
    timer(200).pipe(map(() => `orange #${x}`)),
  ])),
).subscribe(([apple, orange]) => console.log([apple, orange]))
```

This is the equivalent of `Promise.all` and will wait until multiple concurrent `Observable`s have completed, then it will emit once, aggregating the last values emitted by each "inner query".

In the example above, every second (with `interval(1000)`), I spawn two new queries, fetching an apple and an orange, respectively. The query that retrieves an apple completes in 100ms, the one for the orange takes 200ms (with `timer`).

For completeness' sake, here's the output of the above example:

```
[ 'apple #0', 'orange #0' ]
[ 'apple #1', 'orange #1' ]
[ 'apple #2', 'orange #2' ]
[ 'apple #3', 'orange #3' ]
[ 'apple #4', 'orange #4' ]
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. One question though. what if the inner observable does not complete? forkJoin might be an issue then ?

Comment: Ah sorry for not seeing your message before!
If an inner Observable doesn't complete, the corresponding `[apple #1, orange #1]` will hang "forever"... it would need *both* observables to complete, you're right. However, that is, until one second later, when `interval(1000)` emits again, and `switchMap` will take over: if `forkJoin` is still pending, `switchMap` will cancel the on-flight request by unsuscribing from the `forkJoin` that is going to hang forever, create a new `forkJoin` of two new requests for a new apple and a new orange, and subscribe to that one.

Comment: Basically, assuming that the request for `apple #1` never completes, your output there would be: after 1.2s: `[ 'apple #0', 'orange #0']`, after 2.2s: nothing, after 3.2s: `[ 'apple #2', 'orange#2' ]`. It essentially would skip waiting around for the queries that aren't complete by the time the next `switchMap` is triggered.

Comment: Here's a link to some online service where this case is illustrated: https://playcode.io/1316439. Have fun!